# File cannot be downloaded in CentOS

Tags: java

My code is running well on Windows.

```
// this is where the code cracks, tmpFile is a 160kb size file.
File image = HttpUtil.downloadFileFromUrl(url, new File(tmpFile));
```

Here is the reproducible example:

```
@Test
  public void getFileBytes() {
    String DEST = "/home/files/";
    String fileId = "abc";
    String tmpFile = DEST + fileId + "." + "jpeg";

    if (!(FileUtil.exist(DEST) && FileUtil.isDirectory(DEST))) {
      FileUtil.del(DEST);
      new File(DEST).mkdirs();
    }

    String url = "https://images.pexels.com/photos/189349/pexels-photo-189349.jpeg";

    File image = HttpUtil.downloadFileFromUrl(url, new File(tmpFile));

  }
```

The HttpUtil and FileUtil are comes from :

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/cn.hutool/hutool-all -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>cn.hutool</groupId>
    <artifactId>hutool-all</artifactId>
    <version>5.7.19</version>
</dependency>
```

Once I packaged it to war and deployed on CentOS 7.9, the docker container gave NullPointerException.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at cn.hutool.core.io.file.FileReader.checkFile(FileReader.java:299)
        at cn.hutool.core.io.file.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:57)
        at cn.hutool.core.io.file.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:93)
        at cn.hutool.core.io.file.FileReader.create(FileReader.java:46)
        at cn.hutool.core.io.FileUtil.readBytes(FileUtil.java:1878)
        at com.supconit.taishunwenbao.screen.service.impl.ImageServiceImpl.compressImage(ImageServiceImpl.java:87)
        at com.supconit.taishunwenbao.screen.controller.ImageController.compressedImageDownload(ImageController.java:29)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at com.supconit.honeycomb.initAuth.filters.SetUserIdAndUsernameForCloudFilter.doFilterInternal(SetUserIdAndUsernameForCloudFilter.java:39)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1722)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I've gave the folder(where `tmpFile` stays) below permissions:

```
chomd 777 /home/files
```

I've make sure the nginx configuration correct:

```
client_max_body_size 500000m;
```

Is there any reason that cause file download failed?

Comment: Please show the complete exception stack trace, and ideally a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

This is anything but a Java question; else it would be the typical `NullPointerException`.

How about labeling the files with the proper SE Linux security context? https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html-single/selinux_users_and_administrators_guide/index#sect-Managing_Confined_Services-The_Apache_HTTP_Server-The_Apache_HTTP_Server_and_SELinux

For example:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/var/www(/.*)?"
restorecon -R /var/www
```

Also access to user home directories (alike `/home/files`) must be explicitly permitted:

```
sesetbool -P httpd_enable_homedirs on
```

Command `ls -laZ` at least shows the labels. Run `sudo sealert -a /var/log/audit/audit.log` to see all the alerts in the audit log.

Comment: `la -laZ` gives below info:`drwxr-xr-x. root root unconfined_u:object_r:var_t:s0   .
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:var_t:s0 
-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:var_t:s0   Dockerfile
-rw-r--r--. root root unconfined_u:object_r:var_t:s0   app.jar`. What does it mean?

Comment: @Criwran That it's type `var_t` and that `httpd` is not going to serve this under any circumstances. Just read the documentation which I've linked; it explains the relevant types in detail.

Comment: OK, I'll read it. Thanks

Comment: Java application server may require different labels, but it generally is the same.